Interpreting group in normal abelian subgroup of finite index?
I am self-studying Hodges' Model Theory, and exercise 5.3.6 asks:
Show that for $G$ a group with normal abelian subgroup $A$ where $G/A$ is finite, $G$ is interpretable (potentially with parameters) in $A$. It suggests interpreting in the disjoint sum $A + \ldots + A$ which by the previous exercise is interpretable in $A$, so you may compose these interpretations for proof.
I did the previous exercise, and am thinking of the following for a proof:
I interpret in $A + \ldots + A$, the $|G/A|$-fold disjoint sum. Recall that this comes equipped with a copy of A's language for each copy of A and a relation for each copy that holds exactly on its copy.
Choose coset representatives (using $G/A$ finite) $h_1, \ldots, h_n$ so each element has unique representation $h_ia$, $a \in A$. I take the trivial domain formula $x=x$ and trivial equality formula $x=y$, and coordinate map $f$($a$ in $h_i$'s copy of $A$) = $h_ia$.
But then for multiplication:
We want $h_1a_1h_2a_2=h_3a_3$ aka $f(x_1)f(x_2)=f(x_3) \iff \phi(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ holds for some $\phi$...
First, I can see that $x_3$ must be in the coset of $h_1h_2$. This can be expressed by writing out the (finite) multiplication table of $G/A$:
Let $P_i$ by the relation identifying the coset of $h_i$. Then we'd have something like $(P_{i_1}x_1 \wedge P_{i_2}x_2 \wedge P_{i_3}x_3) \vee \ldots$ going through each pair of cosets and their product coset.
However, I don't know how to finish this off and actually check that $h_1a_1h_2a_2=h_3a_3$. Obviously, I haven't used that $A$ is abelian (or parameters in $A + \ldots + A$ if need be), and I don't see how these help.
(Recall that once we have multiplication, inversion and the identity are first-order definable).
I appreciate any help as always.

I think the exercise is wrong, or at least that the method suggested in the hint doesn't work.
Let $A$ be an abelian group with an involution $\varphi\colon A\to A$ which is not definable. For example, let $A = \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$, and let $\varphi\colon A\to A$ be the automorphism $\varphi(a,b) = (a,-b)$. A definable function commutes with every automorphism, but $\varphi$ fails to commute with the automorphism $\psi\colon A\to A$, $\psi(a,b) = (b,a)$, so it is not definable.
Now let $G$ be the semidirect product $A\rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, where the non-identity element $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $A$ by $\varphi$. Then $A$ is normal in $G$, and $G/A\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is finite.
Following the hint in Hodges, we interpret $A_0\sqcup A_1$ in $A$, where $A_0$ and $A_1$ are two copies of $A$. Here $a\in A_i$ represents the element $(a,i)$ in $G$. Suppose the multiplication of $G$ was definable in $A$ on $A_0\sqcup A_1$. Then the following map $A_0\to A_0$ would also be definable: $$(a,0)\mapsto (0,1)\cdot (a,0)\cdot (0,1) = (0+\varphi(a)+0,1+0+1) = (\varphi(a),0).$$ But then $\varphi\colon A\to A$ would be definable, contradiction.

Taking a step back, suppose $G$ is a group, $N\trianglelefteq G$ (not necessarily abelian), and $H = G/N$ is finite. What would we need to interpret $G$ in $N$?
Writing $H = \{h_1,\dots,h_m\}$, we can pick representatives $g_1,\dots,g_m\in G$ such that $g_iN = h_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq m$. Then for all $1\leq i,j\leq m$, if $h_ih_j = h_k$, we have $g_ig_jN = g_kN$, so there is some $n_{i,j}\in N$ such that $g_ig_j = g_kn_{i,j}$.
Also, for each $1\leq i\leq m$, conjugation by $g_i^{-1}$ gives an automorphism $f_i\colon N\to N$, defined by $f_i(n) = g_i^{-1}ng_i$.
Now given $g,g'\in G$, we can write $g = g_in$ and $g' = g_jn'$ for some $1\leq i,j\leq m$ and $n,n'\in N$. Suppose $h_ih_j = h_k$. Then we have
\begin{align*}
gg' &= g_ing_jn'\\
&= g_ig_j(g_j^{-1}ng_j)n'\\
&= g_kn_{i,j}f_j(n)n'.
\end{align*}
This shows that $G$ is interpretable in the structure $(N,(f_i)_{i=1}^m,(n_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^m)$. Or, putting it another way, if each $f_i$ is definable with parameters in $N$, then $G$ is interpretable in $N$, with parameters $(n_{i,j})_{i,j=1}^m$ together with those parameters used to define the $(f_i)_{i=1}^m$.
Indeed, we can interpret the disjoint sum $N_1+\dots+N_m$ in $N$ and then define the multiplication $N_i\times N_j\to N_k$ (where $h_ih_j = h_k$) by $(n,n')\mapsto n_{i,j}f_j(n)n'$.
As a consequence, if $G$ itself is abelian, then $G$ is interpretable (with parameters) in $N$, since each $f_i$ is the identity automorphism. I suspect this is what Hodges was thinking of when he wrote the exercise - it explains the otherwise seemly irrelevant hypothesis that $A$ is abelian.
At the other extreme, if every automorphism of $N$ is inner (so $N$ is far from being abelian), then $G$ is interpretable (with parameters) in $N$, since each $f_i$ is conjugation by some $k_i\in N$, and hence definable using $k_i$ as a parameter.
